# Add column to pandas df depending on a condition statement

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df called `lin_reg_df` with two columns `Surface_Elevation_mAHD` and `Adopted_SS_WL`.
The df holds measurements of each for 88 groundwater wells that each have a particular well name.
`lin_reg_df` is indexed by `well name`.
I want to add another column to the df that is called `Aquifer_Type` and specifies if the well is `deep` or `shallow`. 
The well names of all the `deep` wells are held in a list called `deep_wells` and shallow wells are held in `shallow_wells`
I want to cycle through the well names (index of the df) and if the well name is listed in the 
list called `deep_wells` I want to put a `deep` in the `Aquifer_Type` column.  If it is listed
in the list called `shallow_wells` I want to put a `shallow` in the `Aquifer_Type` column.
I tried using isin within the loop but I couldnt get it to work.
Any advice?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a minimum example from your information, with following code:

```py
well_name = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
deep_wells = ['a','c','g']
shallow_wells = ['b','d','e','f']

lin_reg_df = pd.DataFrame({'Surface_Elevation_mAHD ': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                           'Adopted_SS_WL': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]})
lin_reg_df.index = well_names
```

so my DataFrame initially looks like this:

```py
    Surface_Elevation_mAHD  Adopted_SS_WL
a   1                       0.1
b   2                       0.2
c   3                       0.3
d   4                       0.4
e   5                       0.5
f   6                       0.6
g   7                       0.7
```

I would then just use this code snippet to do the job:

```py
for well in well_name:
    if well in deep_wells:
        lin_reg_df.loc[well, 'Aquifier_Type'] = 'deep'
    elif well in shallow_wells:
        lin_reg_df.loc[well, 'Aquifier_Type'] = 'shallow'
```

The output will be:

```
    Surface_Elevation_mAHD  Adopted_SS_WL   Aquifier_Type
a   1                       0.1             deep
b   2                       0.2             shallow
c   3                       0.3             deep
d   4                       0.4             shallow
e   5                       0.5             shallow
f   6                       0.6             shallow
g   7                       0.7             deep
```

Answer (score 0):

Always give data to get help faster

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Surface_Elevation_mAHD':[3,4,6,7.8,9,2,5],'Adopted_SS_WL':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'well name':['WQ','RT','KL','SZ','TR','YH','YP']})
df
```

Lists

```
deep_wells=['WQ','RT','YH','YP']
shallow_wells=['KL','SZ','TR']
```

One other way is to use `np.where` for `numpy.where(condition,yes,no`)

```
df['Aquifer_Type']= np.where(df['well name'].isin(shallow_wells), 'shallow_wells', 'deep_wells')
df
```

If your well name is the index. Please reset it before applying np.wehere. You do that by `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`